# Number of components in Principal Components Analysis with mixed data

Tags: r, pca, mixed-type-data

How can I decide about the optimal number of components in Principal component analysis when I have mixed data of of categorical and continuous?

I'm using `package PCAmixdata` for PCA and I wish to know the number of optimal components. in this package we can have he PCA metrics by using the following forumla:

```
obj <- PCAmix(X.quanti = X1 , X.quali = X2, ndim = 2, rename.level=TRUE)
```

where `ndim` is number of components (dimension)

But, how do I know what is the optimal number of `ndim` ?

Comment: I don't know about the package you are using but in theory you choose the N dimensions which cover 92% of your datas variance or more

Comment: That value of 92% is so arbitrary that it's *essential* you provide some support for it.